# Find unique array of tuples

Tags: collections, f#, duplicates

I have 4 arrays of different data. For the first array of string, I want to delete the duplicate element and get the results of array of unique tuples with 4 elements.

For example, let's say the arrays are:

```
let dupA1 = [| "A"; "B"; "C"; "D"; "A" |]

let dupA2 = [| 1; 2; 3; 4; 1 |]

let dupA3 = [| 1.0M; 2.0M; 3.0M; 4.0M; 1.0M |]

let dupA4 = [| 1L; 2L; 3L; 4L; 1L |]
```

I want the result to be:

```
let uniqueArray = [| ("A", 1, 1.0M, 1L); ("B", 2, 2.0M, 2L); ("C", 3, 3.0M, 3L); ("D",4, 4.0M, 4L) |]
```

Comment: So you want to zip them together per item? What if arrays contains different number of items?

Comment: You checked (V mark) my answer. if  you want give to the Ramon's answer, You can change it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let zip4 s1 s2 s3 s4 =
  Seq.map2 (fun (a,b)(c,d) ->a,b,c,d) (Seq.zip s1 s2)(Seq.zip s3 s4)

let uniqueArray = zip4 dupA1 dupA2 dupA3 dupA4 |> Seq.distinct |> Seq.toArray
```

Answer (score 4):

You will first need to write a zip4 function which will zip the arrays:

```
// the function assumes the 4 arrays are of the same length
let zip4 a (b : _ []) (c : _ []) (d : _ []) =
    Array.init (Array.length a) (fun i -> a.[i], b.[i], c.[i], d.[i])
```

Then a distinct function for arrays, using `Seq.distinct`:

```
let distinct s = Seq.distinct s |> Array.ofSeq
```

And the result would be:

```
> zip4 dupA1 dupA2 dupA3 dupA4 |> distinct;;
val it : (string * int * decimal * int64) [] =
  [|("A", 1, 1.0M, 1L); ("B", 2, 2.0M, 2L); ("C", 3, 3.0M, 3L);
    ("D", 4, 4.0M, 4L)|]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Actually, my real problem has 8 arrays of different data type, since I don't know how to write the code like Zip4, as F# has only zip3 at the most; then it is difficult for me to figure out how to find the unique array of tuples.\